# Error <identifier> expected

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a basic android app that opens a website on startup. This is my code so far, but I'm getting an "error  expected" error. I'm coding in android studio.

```
package com.cryptocrea.sitr;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    string urel = "http://cryptocrea.com/";
    Webview view = (Webview) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
       // view.getsettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(urel);
}
```

Comment: Your code needs to be in method not class level

Answer (score 1):

Try this do **`findViewById`** inside `onCreate()` method

And also there is typo check it  a **`WebView`** & **`String`** not **`Webview`** & **`string`**

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String urel = "http://cryptocrea.com/";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
       // view.getsettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(urel);

    }

}
```

Comment: Its now giving me the errors "cannot find symbol class string" and "cannot find symbol class Webview"

Comment: Check your java version..jdk etc

Comment: **to down-voter God Bless You

keep patience karma will work**

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling anything in the Main OnCreate method.So you app is getting created and nothing else happens.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   string urel = "http://cryptocrea.com/";
   Webview view = (Webview) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
   view.loadUrl(urel);
}

}
```

Please refer Android activity lifecycle before you develop apps:https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html
Hope that helps